# Partial groupId for Maven Archetype - preventing duplicate groupId in folder structure

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I'd like to use

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.${groupId}</groupId>
```

In my archetype-generated projects, instead of

```
<groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
```

is that possible? It seems to work ok for poms, but for actual files I have

```
src/main/java/com/mycompany/__groupId__/__rootArtifactId__
```

file structure, but using the archetype Maven generates them as

```
src/main/java/__groupId__/com/mycompany/__groupId__/__rootArtifactId__
```

in the file system. I don't get where the extra groupId is coming from and how can I prevent it.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm trying to use __groupId__ in the module name, but it doesn't work.

Comment: if I had, this question would be answered :)

Comment: Would you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021671/use-groupid-in-archetype