# Use __groupId__ in archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a multi module archetype like the following:

```
__groupId__.plugin
__groupId__.feature
```

I want to set the names of the modules by groupId. So I use `__groupId__` In order to set the module names. The problem is that  these template doesn't get recognized. When I use `__rootArtifactId__` my code works. Am I using the wrong template name?

I have the following structure:

```
archetype
 |--src
    |--main
        |--resources
            |--sonatype-resources
            |   |--__groupId__.plugin
            |   |--__groupId__.feature
            |   |--pom.xml
            |---META-INF
                |---maven
                    |---archetype-metadata.xml
```

The module description in archetype-metadata.xml looks like this:

```
<module id="${groupId}.plugin" dir="__groupId__.parent" name="${groupId}.plugin">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory></directory>
      <includes>
        <include>.project</include>
        <include>build.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</module>
<module id="${groupId}.parent" dir="__groupId__.feature" name="${groupId}.feature">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory></directory>
      <includes>
        <include>.project</include>
        <include>build.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</module>
```

Comment: `<module id="${groupId}.parent" dir="__groupId__.feature" ` makes no sense, it's either `${groupId}` or `__groupId__` in given context, not both...

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using the "packaged" property of the fileSet. By using it you can alter the "package" property default value and adding the files directly in the customized folder.